# In Power BI, How to dynamically get value of last row for each group and summarize it

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

In a Power BI (Desktop) project I'm trying to dynamically get value of last row for each group and show its summary in a Pie visual.

My simplified data here has Users. Each user has Forms ranked by form Id. It also has another dimension 'form subject' that multiplying the rows per subject Id.

I've created a Measure that return `1` if the current form is the last form of user. The Measure is being dynamically calculated when filtering to a shorter period with the dates slicer. (UPDATED. I couldn't dynamically calculate it before. The Measure code updated accordingly.)

I've added a Pie visual that count forms with filter based on my Measure assuming only the last forms for each user will be counted, the result wasn't as expected as shown in the image. Without the filter, all the forms are counted and the result as expected.

**Actual result:**

[image]

**Expected result:**

Based on the data in the bottom, I want to be able to see a Pie that count for each user the result of the last form as it appears in the small table in the image of the actual result - When filtering all the dates between 1-4/1/23 the Pie will show 3 for the FormResultID 4 and 1 for the FormResultID 2. Then, when filtering between 1-2/1/23 the Pie will show 2 for the FormResultID 1 and 2 for the FormResultID 2.

The small table visual in the image is giving me the expected result but I couldn't figure how to get the same results in the Pie visual.

I've tried many solutions that was suggested here and in other relative forums but with no success.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Measure code:**

```
IsLastUserForm = 
  VAR MaxFormID = MAXX(
    ALLSELECTED (Sheet1),
    CALCULATE(MAX(Sheet1[FormID]), VALUES(Sheet1[UserID]))
  )
RETURN
  CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Sheet1[FormID]),
    FILTER(Sheet1,Sheet1[FormID] = MaxFormID)
  )
```

**Data:**

| UserID | FormDate | FormID | FormResultID | FormSubjectID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 01/01/2023 | 1001 | 2 | 11 |
| 101 | 01/01/2023 | 1001 | 2 | 12 |
| 101 | 01/01/2023 | 1001 | 2 | 13 |
| 101 | 02/01/2023 | 1002 | 1 | 11 |
| 101 | 02/01/2023 | 1002 | 1 | 12 |
| 101 | 02/01/2023 | 1002 | 1 | 13 |
| 101 | 03/01/2023 | 1003 | 4 | 11 |
| 101 | 03/01/2023 | 1003 | 4 | 12 |
| 101 | 03/01/2023 | 1003 | 4 | 13 |
| 102 | 01/01/2023 | 1004 | 2 | 11 |
| 102 | 01/01/2023 | 1004 | 2 | 12 |
| 102 | 01/01/2023 | 1004 | 2 | 13 |
| 102 | 02/01/2023 | 1005 | 2 | 11 |
| 102 | 02/01/2023 | 1005 | 2 | 12 |
| 102 | 02/01/2023 | 1005 | 2 | 13 |
| 102 | 03/01/2023 | 1006 | 1 | 11 |
| 102 | 03/01/2023 | 1006 | 1 | 12 |
| 102 | 03/01/2023 | 1006 | 1 | 13 |
| 102 | 04/01/2023 | 1007 | 4 | 11 |
| 102 | 04/01/2023 | 1007 | 4 | 12 |
| 102 | 04/01/2023 | 1007 | 4 | 13 |
| 103 | 01/01/2023 | 1008 | 2 | 11 |
| 103 | 01/01/2023 | 1008 | 2 | 12 |
| 103 | 01/01/2023 | 1008 | 2 | 13 |
| 103 | 02/01/2023 | 1009 | 1 | 11 |
| 103 | 02/01/2023 | 1009 | 1 | 12 |
| 103 | 02/01/2023 | 1009 | 1 | 13 |
| 103 | 03/01/2023 | 1010 | 4 | 11 |
| 103 | 03/01/2023 | 1010 | 4 | 12 |
| 103 | 03/01/2023 | 1010 | 4 | 13 |
| 104 | 01/01/2023 | 1011 | 1 | 11 |
| 104 | 01/01/2023 | 1011 | 1 | 12 |
| 104 | 01/01/2023 | 1011 | 1 | 13 |
| 104 | 02/01/2023 | 1012 | 2 | 11 |
| 104 | 02/01/2023 | 1012 | 2 | 12 |
| 104 | 02/01/2023 | 1012 | 2 | 13 |

Comment: Based on the table data you give, can you clarify one or two of your expected results? I asm struggling to match the expected results for the examples you give with the dataset provided.

Comment: I would like to have a Pie that sum `FormResultID` of the last form of each user. In SQL I could get it easily using `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY FormDate DESC) AS Rn` and then filtering to have only the rows with `Rn = 1`

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood. I meant that I can't see how you arrive at the expected results you give based on the table data you provided. For example, when you say "*when filtering all the dates between 1-4/1/23 the Pie will show 3 for the FormResultID 4 and 1 for the FormResultID 2*" I don't see how you get these figures from that data.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to shred it - In the case that you mentioned, the last form of user 101 is form 1003 with result `4`. the last form of user 102 is form 1007 with result `4`. the last form of user 103 is form 1010 with result `4`. the last form of user 104 is form 1012 with result `2`. If we sum it we get 3 times the `4` result and one time the `2` result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go.

[image]

[image]

```
Measure = 
VAR t = 
CALCULATETABLE(
ADDCOLUMNS(
    SUMMARIZE(
       UserTable, 
       UserTable[UserID]
    ),
    "@id",
    CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANKVALUE(UserTable[FormDate], MAX(UserTable[FormResultID]))),
    "@date",
    CALCULATE(LASTNONBLANKVALUE(UserTable[FormDate], MAX(UserTable[FormDate])))

), ALLSELECTED())

RETURN 

COUNTROWS(FILTER(t, [@id] = SELECTEDVALUE(UserTable[FormResultID])))
```

Comment: Works perfect with over 12M records

Comment: Great stuff. Glad to hear.